# Pandas concatenate columns using pd.eval

Tags: python, pandas, eval

Is it possible to concatenate columns together like in the example below using `pd.eval`? I keep getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'object' and '<class 'str'>'`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 'x'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 'y'}])

df['a'].astype('str') + '_' + df['b']
# 0    1_x
# 1    2_y
# dtype: object

pd.eval("df['a'].astype('str') + '_' + df['b']")
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'object' and '<class 'str'>'
```

Comment: You can't call method inside `eval`, it's not an `exec` command. Check the documentation of `numexpr`. Certain functions are supported but class method is not.

Comment: Okay, I also tried using `engine=python` and that didn't help. I guess I may just need to use Python's `eval` instead

Comment: Could you elaborate, why are you trying to do this? Maybe there's a better way (I am not a big fan of `pd.eval` )

Comment: It's a data loader where I have a dictionary that lists the raw input column names, desired column name, final data type, and a few other pieces of metadata and notes for each column. So my Python scripts reads and iterates over that to rename/typecast the raw data. This dictionary also includes a column indicating whether any calculation should be applied to the column (for example the raw data has an unneeded suffix to be stripped off, or should be concatenated with another column), and that's what I'm passing to eval in my Python ETL script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) supports Series and DataFrame objects, so you could use the following workaround:

```
pd.eval("df.a.astype('str') + df.assign(underline='_').underline + df.b")
```

Result:

```
0    1_x
1    2_y
dtype: object
```

(I'm not saying this is a reasonable approach, just trying to answer this particular question)